# hibernate: call stored procedure as a part of HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I want to use HQL:

```
select u,
       call some_procedure(m.id)
from User u
```

`some_procedure` is an Oracle stored procedure. Is it possible to use stored procedure inside of Select HQL-Statement?

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions that are unknown to Hibernate can be done by using the `FUNCTION` wrapper: `select u, FUNCTION('some_procedure', u.id) from User u` but that won't work because Hibernate doesn't know how to materialize the result of the function. You will have to wrap a cast around: `select u, cast(FUNCTION('some_procedure', u.id) as String) from User u`